# swift: after adding navigationController to viewController, tableView height is not fitting screen

Tags: swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

after adding this codes to appDelegate inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function:

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
let mainView = PageViewController(coder: NSCoder()) 
let nav1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainView!)
nav1.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
self.window!.rootViewController = nav1
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

tableView height is not looking good, some part of tableView(cells) not fitting screen

my codes for implementing tableView:

```
let myTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height-40))
myTableView.bounces = false
myTableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
myTableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellID")
myTableView.register(MyTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellID2")
myTableView.dataSource = self
myTableView.delegate = self
```

for show all part of tableView in screen i have to change the first line above code to this:

```
let myTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 40, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height-90))
```

why this is happening and what should i do to solve this problem thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this but don't forget to add myTableView as a subview before you set anchors:

```
            myTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            myTableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myTableView.superview!.leftAnchor).isActive = true
            myTableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myTableView.superview!.rightAnchor).isActive = true
            myTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myTableView.superview!.topAnchor).isActive = true
            myTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myTableView.superview!.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: could you please tell me why this is happening

Comment: is there another way to do this? i mean using navigationController and tableView inside viewController

Comment: Could you please provide screenshot of what do you have on screen with your implementation, so I can figure out whats wrong? You made some weird insets on top and on bottom, idk why :(

Comment: "is there another way to do this? i mean using navigationController and tableView inside viewController" - I didn't quite get that

Comment: i define UINavigationController in appDelegate programmatically for UIViewController that contain UITableView , your solution is solve my problem but in objective c i never see this problem , is there another way to add UINavigationController  to UIViewController that contain UITableView

Comment: If you still wanna to init that without using constraints you can try this
let myTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height - nav1.navigationBar.bounds.height ))